# Add an image on top of repeated-gradient image in PHP

Tags: css

I looked around but nothing that I came across seems to be working for what I'm trying to achieve.

I have box and I'm using a gradient/background. The box asks the user if he wants to buy the product for a friend so I want to add a gift photo in there as well. The problem is that the gift photo appears in  the back of the other image and I cannot find a way to fix it.

Btw I'm working on WP using a theme.

Here's the code I have:

PHP

```
<div class="gift boxed3">
                    <span class="gift_title">
                           <?php gb_e('Buy for friend') ?>
                    </span>
                </div>
```

CSS

```
.gift{
font-size: 0.6em;
font-family: Arial;
float:left;
}


.gift_title {
color: #666666;
font-size: 15px;
font-family: arial;
font-weight: bold;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top: 10px;
line-height: 66px;
}

.boxed3 {
width: 297px;
height:65px;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
margin-top: 15px;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
background-image: url(http://domain.gr/example/gradient.png);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-position: center bottom;
border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #7D7D7D;
}
```

Comment: Since no once can see what "gb_e('Buy for friend')" output is, I don't think anyone can help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Diodeus. It doesn't really have any functionality it's just the text displayed in the box.
I'm not really familiar with php, so I hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case that post helps someone in the future. This is how I managed to fix the problem I was facing.

Note: I am working on WordPress.

```
<div class="gift boxed3">
                     <span class="gift_image">
                            <img src="http://topgreekgyms.fitnessforum.gr/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/gift.png";?>
                     </span>

                     <span class="gift_title">
                            <a href="<?php gb_add_to_cart_url(); ?>" class=""><?php gb_e('Buy for friend') ?></a>
                      </span>
                </div>
```

CSS

```
.gift{
    font-size: 0.6em;
    font-family: Arial;
    float:left;
    }

    .gift_title {
    color: #666;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    line-height: 66px;
    }

    .gift_image {
    float: left;
    margin: 16px 9px;
    }

    .boxed3 {
    width: 297px;
    height:65px;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    margin-top: 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    background-image: url(http://topgreekgyms.fitnessforum.gr/wp-content/themes/blank-child-theme/img/gradient.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: center bottom;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #7D7D7D;
    }
```